# How can I rank based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rank

Supposed, I have Pandas DataFrame looks like below:

| Cluster | Variable | Group | Ratio | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GDP_M3 | GDP | 20% | 70% |
| 1 | HPI_M6 | HPI | 40% | 80% |
| 1 | GDP_lg2 | GDP | 35% | 50% |
| 2 | CPI_M9 | CPI | 10% | 50% |
| 2 | HPI_lg6 | HPI | 15% | 65% |
| 3 | CPI_lg12 | CPI | 15% | 90% |
| 3 | CPI_lg1 | CPI | 20% | 95% |

I would like to rank `Variable` based on `Ratio` and `Value` in the separated columns. The `Ratio` will rank from the lowest to the highest, while the `Value` will rank from the highest to the lowest.

There are some variables that I do not want to rank. In the example, I do not prefer `CPI`. Any type of `CPI` will not be considered for the rank e.g., `CPI_M9`. However, the case will be expected only if there is only that particular variable in the `Cluster`.

The results from condition above will look like the table below:

| Cluster | Variable | Group | Ratio | Value | RankRatio | RankValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GDP_M3 | GDP | 20% | 70% | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | HPI_M6 | HPI | 40% | 80% | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | GDP_lg2 | GDP | 35% | 50% | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | CPI_M9 | CPI | 10% | 50% | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | HPI_lg6 | HPI | 15% | 65% | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | CPI_lg12 | CPI | 15% | 90% | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | CPI_lg1 | CPI | 20% | 95% | 2 | 1 |

For Cluster 1, the `GDP_M3` has the lowest `Ratio` at `20%`, while the `HPI_M3` has the highest `Value` at `80%`. Thus, both of them will be assigned rank 1 and the others will be followed subsequently.

For Cluster 2, even `CPI_M9` has the lowest Ratio but the `CPI` is not prefer. Thus, the rank 1 will be assigned to `HPI_lg6`.

For Cluster 3, there are variables from the only `CPI` Group and there is no other options to rank. Thus, the `CPI_lg12` and `CPI_lg1` are ranked based on the lowest `Ratio` and the highest `Value`.

```
df['RankRatio'] = df.groupby(['Cluster'])['Ratio'].rank(method = 'first', ascending = True)
df['RankValue'] = df.groupby(['Cluster'])['Value'].rank(method = 'first', ascending = False)
```

I have some code that can be handled only general case but for specific case with unprefer group of variables, my code cannot handle it.

Please help or suggest on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert columns to numeric
df[['Ratio','Value']]=df[['Ratio','Value']].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('%')).astype(float)
```

Remove row with `CPI` by condition - test rows if no only `CPI` per `Cluster`:

```
m = df['Group'].eq('CPI')
m1 = ~df['Cluster'].isin(df.loc[m, 'Cluster']) | m
df['RankRatio'] = df[m1].groupby('Cluster')['Ratio'].rank(method='first', ascending=True)
df['RankValue'] = df[m1].groupby('Cluster')['Value'].rank(method='first', ascending=False)


print (df)
   Cluster  Variable Group  Ratio  Value  RankRatio  RankValue
0        1    GDP_M3   GDP   20.0   70.0        1.0        2.0
1        1    HPI_M6   HPI   40.0   80.0        3.0        1.0
2        1   GDP_lg2   GDP   35.0   50.0        2.0        3.0
3        2    CPI_M9   CPI   10.0   50.0        NaN        NaN
4        2   HPI_lg6   HPI   15.0   65.0        1.0        1.0
5        3  CPI_lg12   CPI   15.0   90.0        1.0        2.0
6        3   CPI_lg1   CPI   20.0   95.0        2.0        1.0
```

How it working:

For `mask2` are filter all `Cluster` values if match `mask1` and filtered original column `Cluster`, then invert mask by `~`. Last chain both conditions by `|` for bitwise `OR` for all rows without `CPI` if exist with another values per `Cluster`:

```
print (df.assign(mask1 = m, mask2 = ~df['Cluster'].isin(df.loc[m, 'Cluster']), both = m1))
   Cluster  Variable Group  Ratio  Value  mask1  mask2   both
0        1    GDP_M3   GDP   20.0   70.0  False   True   True
1        1    HPI_M6   HPI   40.0   80.0  False   True   True
2        1   GDP_lg2   GDP   35.0   50.0  False   True   True
3        2    CPI_M9   CPI   10.0   50.0   True  False   True
4        2   HPI_lg6   HPI   15.0   65.0  False  False  False
5        3  CPI_lg12   CPI   15.0   90.0   True  False   True
6        3   CPI_lg1   CPI   20.0   95.0   True  False   True
```

EDIT:

```
df[['Ratio','Value']]=df[['Ratio','Value']].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('%')).astype(float)

m = df['Group'].isin(['CPI','HPI'])
m2 = df.groupby('Cluster')['Group'].transform('nunique').ne(1)
m1 = (~df['Cluster'].isin(df.loc[~m, 'Cluster']) | m) & m2
df['RankRatio'] = df[~m1].groupby('Cluster')['Ratio'].rank(method='first', ascending=True)
df['RankValue'] = df[~m1].groupby('Cluster')['Value'].rank(method='first', ascending=False)
print (df)
   Cluster  Variable Group  Ratio  Value  RankRatio  RankValue
0        1    GDP_M3   GDP   20.0   70.0        1.0        1.0
1        1    HPI_M6   HPI   40.0   80.0        NaN        NaN
2        1   GDP_lg2   GDP   35.0   50.0        2.0        2.0
3        2    CPI_M9   CPI   10.0   50.0        NaN        NaN
4        2   HPI_lg6   HPI   15.0   65.0        NaN        NaN
5        3  CPI_lg12   CPI   15.0   90.0        1.0        2.0
6        3   CPI_lg1   CPI   20.0   95.0        2.0        1.0
```

---

```
print (df.assign(mask1 = m, mask2 = ~df['Cluster'].isin(df.loc[~m, 'Cluster']), m2=m2, all = ~m1))
   Cluster  Variable Group  Ratio  Value  RankRatio  RankValue  mask1  mask2  \
0        1    GDP_M3   GDP   20.0   70.0        1.0        1.0  False  False   
1        1    HPI_M6   HPI   40.0   80.0        NaN        NaN   True  False   
2        1   GDP_lg2   GDP   35.0   50.0        2.0        2.0  False  False   
3        2    CPI_M9   CPI   10.0   50.0        NaN        NaN   True   True   
4        2   HPI_lg6   HPI   15.0   65.0        NaN        NaN   True   True   
5        3  CPI_lg12   CPI   15.0   90.0        1.0        2.0   True   True   
6        3   CPI_lg1   CPI   20.0   95.0        2.0        1.0   True   True   

      m2    all  
0   True   True  
1   True  False  
2   True   True  
3   True  False  
4   True  False  
5  False   True  
6  False   True
```

Comment: Could you explain the first two lines of the second chunk code?

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - answer was edited.

Comment: what if I have more than 1 variables to filter out? I have tried to use .isin() instead of .eq() but it doesn't work.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Based on the example I would like to filter only CPI in the Group. However, when applying with real data, I would like to filter more than 1 values in the Group. For example, CPI and HPI.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - hmm, so `df['Group'].isin(['CPI','HPI'])` not working?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. It seems like it valid only 1 values for filter.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - testing in sample data

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha hmmm, isin here means `CPI` OR `HPI`, so expected ouput is added to answer. Do you need something else?

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - do you need `CPI` and `HPI` ?

Comment: No, the CPI and HPI are not preferred. Thus, these variables should not be ranked unless there is only these kind of variables purely contained in the particular cluster.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - what is expected ouput for column `RankValue`  form sample data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244503/discussion-between-sasiwut-chaiyadecha-and-jezrael).

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - answer was edited.